# TFS Work Item query in Visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs

With reference to the answer provided in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015195/how-do-i-run-a-tfs-work-item-query-with-visual-studio-macros/5089198#5089198) I have a question?

What if we have the access to only one project in among many projects in the Team foundation server?

i.e. when I am trying to test the code in the link below, it is stopping at connect method:

```
    workItemStore = New WorkItemStore(teamProjectCollection)
    proj = workItemStore.Projects(projectName)
```

on the first line.

So are there any methods to connect to a single project directly without accessing project collection?

Comment: you can increase the quality of this question by not only linking to the original post, but to include some more verbose context for your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you should still be able to connect. If you have access to a single Team Project on TFS you will be able to retrieve the WorkItemStore object. You should do the following:

> WorkItemStore = teamProjectCollection.GetService(of WorkItemStore)

This will likely solve your issue.