# VSIX extension - closing windows that do not seem to have vsWindowKind constants

Tags: c#, guid, vsix, visual-studio-2017

In my Visual Studio extension, I can close a window in the IDE by doing this:

```
var dte = (DTE)GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));
dte.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindOutput).Close();
```

(That closes the output window)

There are windows which do not seem to have a "vsWindowKind" constant (all of which are listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.constants.aspx) - you can still close them if you know the GUID. For example:

```
dte.Windows.Item("{131369F2-062D-44A2-8671-91FF31EFB4F4}").Close();
```

closes the Team Explorer window (I found that GUID from another SO question: [How do I run a TFS Work Item Query with Visual Studio Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015195/how-do-i-run-a-tfs-work-item-query-with-visual-studio-macros).

My question is, where can I find a complete list of IDE window GUIDs?

EDIT: so for VS2015 and below I can find a list of tool windows in the registry by doing the following:

```
var keyname = @"Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\ToolWindows";
using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyname))
{
    foreach (var subkey in key.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        var fullkey = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\" + keyname + "\\" + subkey;
        var name = (string)Registry.GetValue(fullkey, "Name", "");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
                Console.WriteLine($"{subkey} {name}");
        }
    }
}
```

However, there are no such entries for VS2017 (probably because it allows you to install multiple copies on the same PC).

Anyway, the documented list is still missing!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current window GUID with **DTE.ActiveWindow.ObjectKind**. This way you can build the list of IDE window GUIDs yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Is this you're looking for? The vsWindowType Enumeration documentation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.vswindowtype.aspx